# Explaining LLVM for loop

Tags: for-loop, llvm, opcode

I am following along this post however I am new to C++ and LLVM and need help breaking down what everything means in this for loop

```
for(auto I = inst_begin(F), E = inst_end(F); I != E; ++I) {

  Instruction &Inst = *I;

  if(Inst.getOpcode() == Instruction::SDiv) {

    errs() << "Found Signed Division Instruction!\n"; 

  }

}
```

I seem to understand what's going on inside the for loop with the if statement, however I don't understand what 'inst_begin' and 'inst_end' are doing and 'I != E' as well as 'Instruction &Int = *I' I know the *I is referencing the original value of an allocated memory address..? I guess I also need a reference for how 'for loops' are written in LLVM as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is a valid C/C++ code. I'm not familiar with LLVM, so I might be not fully correct:

1. `inst_begin(F)` returns a pointer to the first instruction within some code block `F` (a function?)
2. `inst_end(F)` returns a pointer **after** the last valid instruction in a code block `F`
3. `I != E` is an exit condition for the `for` loop - repeat some steps **until** this condition becomes *false*. If it's false - exit from the loop. `I++` moves your pointer to the next instruction in between `inst_begin(F)`...`inst_end(F)`
4. `Instruction &Int = *I`. `I` is a pointer to some memory location, basically, it's just a number. `*I` allows you to fetch the instruction itself given some memory address. later, you inspect this instruction.

There is no magic in this code, so get some decent C/C++ text book or MOOC and it will be 100% clear for you.

Comment: "`I != E` is an exit condition for the for loop - repeat some steps until this condition becomes true." It's the other way around: a for loop keeps going *while* its condition is true, not until. Or if you want to phrase it in terms of "until", it loops until the condition becomes **false** (i.e. until the iterator has reached the end in this case).

Comment: Thanks, that's a good catch! I guess heat melted my mind a bit. I'll update the answer with that to keep it complete.

Comment: Would there be a way to figure out what F equals inside of inst_begin(F)? I know it is a function/code block as you say, I am doing this with LLVM, I get use of undeclared identifier F...which makes sense as I am inside bool Prereqs::runOnModule(Module &M) { } however if I try to use M  or M.functions() I get the same error

Comment: Most likely, `F` is a pointer to llvm::Function https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Function.html

Comment: FYI, `inst_begin`/end return iterator objects over a circular intrusive linked list, not an actual pointer.